# webRequest API not working with manifest v3 extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, manifest, firefox-addon-webextensions, manifest.json

I'm trying to migrate an extension which uses the webRequest API from manifest v2 to v3 for both Firefox and Chrome. While it works as expected in Chrome, I can't get the webRequest API to work in Firefox with v3. I don't get any error messages, the callback for the onBeforeRequest event just never gets called.
Here is a minimal example for Firefox:

#### v2 working webRequest API

```
manifest v2
{

    "manifest_version": 2,
 
    "name": "fun",
    "version": "4.0.0",
 

    "background":
    {
       "scripts": ["background.js"],
       "type": "module"   
    },
   
    "permissions":
    [
       "webRequest",
       "<all_urls>"
    ]
 }
```

#### background.js

```js
let callbackFilter = { types: ["main_frame", "sub_frame", "xmlhttprequest", "websocket"], urls: ["<all_urls>"] };

console.log("Background script loaded");

browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(() => {
    console.log("Received request event");
}, callbackFilter, []);
```

#### v3 not working in Firefox

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
 
    "name": "fun",
    "version": "4.0.0",
 

    "background":
    {
       "scripts": ["background.js"],
       "type": "module"   
    },
   
    "permissions":
    [
       "webRequest"
    ],
    "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"]
 }
```

Comment: In Firefox host_permissions are disabled by default and you need to use browser.permissions API or inform the user to grant the permissions manually in about:addons.